# How do I write this in a batch file

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to convert a shell script into a batch file but I am stuck at this place.

I am not quite sure how to convert this line into my batch file.

```
$(echo $(cd $(dirname $0)/../..; pwd))
```

I tried

```
echo %(cd %(dirname %0%)%/.../..; pwd)%
```

but I am not sure if I am right!

Comment: I'm ashamed to say that my Linux shell is rusty. What does your original code do?

Comment: my code is actually to compile something. but actually, I am stuck at other places too.
Right now, I need to copy a file recursively to a particular folder along with user permissions

Comment: @Something Prints the name of the directory that's two levels above the directory where the running script is in.

Comment: Could be made simpler and more robust: `(cd "$(dirname "$0")"/../..; pwd)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do command chaining like this in Batch. If I see that correctly, you want to get the absolute path of the directory two levels above the directory of the currently executed script. You might do this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD %~dp0\..\..
ECHO %CD%
```

Which changes the current directory. To avoid that, use:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD %~dp0\..\..
ECHO %CD%
POPD
```

Comment: let me try this and I'll let you know if this works! Thanks